# Can I enter Germany first with my Estonian Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, germany, estonia

I have a single-entry Estonian visa which I obtained for my travel to Estonia. But, after acquiring that, my husband got a work permit to Germany coinciding with almost the same dates.

So I have decided to accompany my husband to Germany first, for 4-5 days and then go to Estonia. I also have a valid ticket from Frankfurt to Estonia and proof of accommodation.

Can I do this? Can I enter German with an Estonian Schengen visa and then do my trip to Estonia?

Comment: Yes, no, maybe, cheesecake. Who knows? The question lacks vital detail, most importantly your reasons to visit Estonia. If your primary destination is still Estonia then you are good, if not then they might deny entry because they would say, you should've applied to Germany instead. Primary destination means: a) specific reason, like a conference. b) if reasons are equal then length of stay. On another note, I am thoroughly sick of these slipshod written questions, ppl ask this same question every day, why can't people include details and also search this site before burping two sentences up.

Comment: Both duplicates suggested duplicates concern multiple-entry visas; this question concerns a single-entry visa.  Voting to leave open.